# How to use the result of an insert as foreign key in another insert?

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a temporary table with lots of data. I want to populate two persistent tables with excerpts of that data, preferably in one go.

Problem: after insert on `tableA`, I want to reuse the generated `id` as foreign key and add it to the insert for `tableB`. But is that possible at all?

Pseudocode for separated inserts:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (id, col1, col2, col3) 
    SELECT(col1, col2, col3) FROM tmp_table
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = last_insert_id(id);

INSERT INTO tableB (fk_id, col4)
    SELECT (fk_id_from_above, col4) FROM tmp_table
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...
```

These are my tables:

```
//a simple temp table with lots of data
CREATE TABLE tmp_table (
 id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 col1 varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 col2 varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 col3 varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 col... varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 colN varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

//this table should be filled from tmp_table and return the generated id for each row
CREATE TABLE tableA (
 id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 col1 varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 col2 varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 col3 varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

//this table should reference the id from tableA (foreign key)
CREATE TABLE tableB (
 id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 fk_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 col4 varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I want to create a single INSERT, that first inserts into `tableA`, then reuses the generated `id` and persist it together with only some other columns in `tableB`.

Comment: Does the temp table have 3 columns? (col1, col2, col3)? Does tableA have an autoincrement `id` column? It would be better if you showed the `CREATE TABLE` statements for both tableA, tableB and the temp table and some sample (temp) data.

Comment: Does that `SELECT` produce only 1 row?  If so, it might be possible.  If not, it is messier.  Please provide 'real' column names; they are often clues of your intent.

Comment: The select produces only a single result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function, with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tableA
    (col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM tmp_table
ORDER BY id ;

@first_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() - 1 ;

INSERT INTO tableB
    (fk_id, col4) 
SELECT @first_id = @first_id + 1, col4
FROM tmp_table
ORDER BY id ;
```

The `ORDER BY id` is needed in both insert statements because we want the rows from the temp table to be inserted in the same order to both tables.

The first insert (into `tableA`) will give consecutive id values to `tableA.id` column. The first of those values is the returned by the following `LAST_INSERT_ID()` call.

The second insert then uses that value (and increasing it one by one) to provide the same values (as `tableA.id`) to `tableB.fk_id` column.